# jQuery trigger event if key "enter" is hit

Tags: javascript, php

I want to trigger an event when the key "enter" is pressed. M'm using the following code but its not working and I don't know why. I've searched everywhere and I found this code.

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery2.js"></script>

        $('#mess').keypress(function(e){
            var key= e.which;
            if( key == 13){
                $('#anc').click();
                return false;
            }

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <a href="#" id="anc" onclick="start()" > Send</a>
            <input id="mess" style="width:200px" type="text" name="msg"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **:(** Why didnt you put <script></script> around javascript code? Its NOT part of html.

Comment: It looks like you're loading two versions of jQuery. This isn't causing your issue, but it could cause other issues. Also, you have a syntax error because your statement is incomplete: you are missing `});` at the end.

Comment: #Where is closing  `});` ? Why ?

Comment: Rolled back the question. Please don’t correct the code in your question. The question is supposed to have non-working code and the answers are supposed to correct it.

Comment: im correcting it, beacuse its still a valid question..my code still is not trigerring click event on the enter key

Comment: That is irrelevant. If you post a question with your code in its current state, _all_ the errors might be relevant, therefore _all_ the corrections need to be in answer form. Otherwise, you’re progressively invalidating any existing answer.

Comment: hmmm.. i understand..im new so im still getting the hang of it..wont happen again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap your code around the `<script></script>` tags for the browser to read the script. You did it for the external JavaScript files, however you didn't do it for your inline code.

```
<script>
$('#mess').keypress(function(e){
    var key= e.which;
    if( key == 13){
        $('#anc').click();
        return false;
    }
 });
</script>
```

**Edit 1**

Please check the console for any errors, it might be that your `DOM` is not loaded yet and you're trying to manipulate it  so it could be causing errors.

**Edit 2**

Your code is currently incorrect.

```
$('#mess').keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 13) {
      $('#anc').click();
      return false;
  }
 });
```

You were missing the closing part of the `keypress` function.

**Edit 3**

Without the full console information, I can just guess. So I'm going to assume that your `DOM` isn't loaded yet. So wrap you code with the below event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Your code here.
}, false);
```

Your code will run once the `DOM` has loaded.

Comment: @MashhoodAli not working is a very subjective term. What is error that you should tell us. There can be 10000 ways to get error in program. What your console tells is important.

Comment: You have a syntax error because your statement is incomplete: you are missing `});` at the end.

Comment: its not giving any errors...its just not trigerring the event...on enter,..its trigerring event on the anchor tag though

Comment: @MashhoodAli check **Edit 3**.